# I am getting an Exception while serializing an object

Tags: java, jdbc, exception

The exception is

> java.io.notSerializableException :
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SingleByteCharacterSetConverter

```
package business_logics;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;


 public class Purchase implements java.io.Serializable
{
String client;
int purchaseID;
String issue;
String due;
ArrayList<Particulars> myparticulars=new ArrayList();
String personal;
double total;
double otheramount;
double previous;
double grandtotal;
String paymentmode;
double paid;
double cbalance;

public Purchase(int id,String client, String issue, String due,String personal, double otheramount, double previous,String payment )
{
    this.purchaseID=id;
    this.client=client;
    this.issue=issue;
    this.due=due;
    this.personal=personal;
    this.otheramount= otheramount*(-1);
    this.previous=previous;
    this.paymentmode=payment;

}

public void setTransaction(double paid)
{
    this.paid=paid;
    this.cbalance=this.grandtotal+this.paid;
}

public void setParticulars(ArrayList<Particulars> part)
{
    part.stream().map((part1) -> {
        this.myparticulars.add(part1);
        return part1;
    }).forEach((part1) -> {
        total += part1.giveAmount();
    });
    total=total*(-1);
   grandtotal=getGrandTotal();
}

public double getGrandTotal()
{
    return total+otheramount+previous;
}
public double getTotal()
{
    return total;
}

public int getPurchaseID()
{
    return purchaseID;
}

public double getBalnace()
{
    return cbalance;
}

public String getIsuueDate()
{
    return issue;
}

public String getDueDate()
{
    return issue;
}

public double getPaid()
{
    return paid;
}

public double getPrevious()
{
    return previous;
}
public double getOther()
{
    return otheramount;
}

public String fullDetail()
{

   StringBuilder mydata=new StringBuilder();

   mydata.append("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
   mydata.append("\n\t\tClient info !!");
   mydata.append("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
   mydata.append("\nName: ").append(client);

   mydata.append("\nIssue Date: "+issue);
   mydata.append("\nDue Date: "+due);
   mydata.append("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
   mydata.append("\n\t\tItem info");
   mydata.append("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
   mydata.append("\n");
   int i=1;
   for (Particulars myparticular : myparticulars)
   {
        mydata.append(i+" | ");
        mydata.append(myparticular);
        mydata.append("\n");i++;
   }
   mydata.append("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
   mydata.append("\n\t\t\t\tNet Payable : "+"\u20B9 "+total);
   mydata.append("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
   mydata.append("\n");

    mydata.append("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
   mydata.append("\n\t  Other Info !!");
   mydata.append("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
   mydata.append("\n");
  mydata.append("\nPrevious Amount: "+previous);
   mydata.append("\nOther Amount: "+otheramount);
   mydata.append("\nPersonal Note : "+personal);
   mydata.append("\nPayment Mode: "+paymentmode);
   mydata.append("\nTotal Net Payable :"+"\u20B9 "+grandtotal);

   mydata.append("\n");
   mydata.append("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
   mydata.append("\n");
   mydata.append("\nAmount Paid:"+"\u20B9 "+paid);
   mydata.append("\n");
   mydata.append("\nCurrent Balance:"+"\u20B9 "+cbalance);

   mydata.append("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
   return mydata.toString();
}

public boolean updateQuantity() throws Exception
{
    boolean done=true;
    int number=myparticulars.size();

    Iterator<Particulars> iterate=myparticulars.iterator();

    int count=0;
    while(iterate.hasNext())
    {
        count+=iterate.next().updateParticularQuantity();
    }

    if(number!=count)
    {
        done=false;
    }
    return done;
}


public String getPersonal() {
   return personal;
}

}
```

This is the class i am trying to serialize  it from outside like this

```
   public void saveInvoice(Purchase p) throws  Exception
  {
     connect.checkFolderExistence();// working fine !!
     String path="C:\\TechBill\\PurchaseInvoices";
     File location=new File(path);
     if(!(location.exists() && location.isDirectory()))
     {
        location.mkdir();
        saveBill(path,p);
     }
    else
    {
       saveBill(path,p);
    }
  }
  private void saveBill(String path,Purchase p) throws Exception
  {

        path=path+"\\"+purchaseID+".ser";
        File myFile=new File(path);

        FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        ObjectOutputStream obout=new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        obout.writeObject(p);
        obout.close();
        fout.close();

}

public void makePurchase(int client_id,Purchase p) throws Exception
{
    persistPurchase(client_id,p);
    Transaction purchaseTransaction=
    new Transaction(p.getIsuueDate(),p.getGrandTotal(), client_id,    
    p.getPurchaseID(), p.getPaid());
    purchaseTransaction.makeTransaction(false, 1); //working fine in other same case
    updateBalance(client_id,p);
    saveInvoice(p);
}
```

calling the methods in a button action

```
     try 
     {
        double oamt=Double.parseDouble(other.getText());

        String mode=credit.isSelected() ? "credit" : "debit";

        double previ=Double.parseDouble(prev.getText());
        if(prev.getForeground()!=green)
        {
            previ=previ*(-1);
        }

         Purchase purchased=new Purchase(Integer.parseInt(pid.getText()),client.getSelectedItem().toString(),
            formatDate(issue.getDate()),formatDate(due.getDate()),notes.getText(),oamt,previ,mode);

         purchased.setParticulars(myParticulars());


        if(!mode.equalsIgnoreCase("credit"))
        {
             purchased.setTransaction(Double.parseDouble(pai.getText()));
        }
        else
        {
            purchased.setTransaction(Double.parseDouble("0.0"));
        }


        String clientname=getClientName(client.getSelectedItem().toString()).trim();
        String clientcity=getClientCity(client.getSelectedItem().toString()).trim();
          System.out.println(purchased.fullDetail());
        if(purchased.updateQuantity())
        {
            makePurchase(getClientID(clientname, clientcity), purchased);


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Quantity successfully Updated");
            //jasper report....
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Quantity Not Updated");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the code related to Database manipulation and fetching is as follows:

```
private void persistPurchase(int id,Purchase p) throws Exception
{
    String query="insert into purchase values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    PreparedStatement ps=connect.giveConnection().prepareStatement(query);

    ps.setInt(1, purchaseID);
    ps.setInt(2, id);
    ps.setString(3, toDataBase(p.getIsuueDate()));
    ps.setString(4, toDataBase(p.getDueDate()));
    ps.setInt(5, particulartable.getModel().getRowCount());
    ps.setDouble(6, p.getPrevious());
    ps.setDouble(7, p.getOther());
    ps.setDouble(8, p.getGrandTotal());
    ps.setString(9, p.getPersonal());
    ps.executeUpdate();
}

public void updateBalance(int id,Purchase p) throws Exception
{
    String query="update net_balance set Balance="+p.getBalnace()+"where     
     client_id="+id;
    Statement stmt=new       
    ConnectionSeeker().giveConnection().createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate(query);
}
```

The `makeTransaction()` method is defined in Transaction class and this method is all working in other case..

```
public void makeTransaction(boolean type,int i) throws Exception //type   
specifies SELL-  true(CREDIT) & PURCHASE- false(DEBIT)....
{
   String query="insert into stransaction values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    PreparedStatement ps=new 
    ConnectionSeeker().giveConnection().prepareStatement(query);

    int no=fetchTransID();

    ps.setString(1,toDataBase(issuedate));
    ps.setString(2,getbillType(i));
    ps.setInt(3,bill_id);
    ps.setInt(4,client_id);
    ps.setInt(5,no);
    ps.setDouble(6,amount);

    double cbalance=0;//amount-saveamount;

    if(type)
    {
        cbalance=cbalance+(amount-saveamount);
        ps.setDouble(7,0.0);
        ps.setDouble(8,round(saveamount, 2));
        ps.setDouble(9,round(cbalance,2));
    }
    else
    {
        cbalance=cbalance+(amount+saveamount);
        ps.setDouble(7,saveamount);
        ps.setDouble(8,0.0);
        ps.setDouble(9, round(cbalance, 2));
    }

    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

The Exception is occuring while execution of `makePurchase()` in the button click inside the `if(purchased.updateQuantity())`

I am getting this exception can please annybody tell me the root cause of occurence of the same. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The root cause is that you're trying to serialize a `SingleByteCharacterSetConverter` directly or indirectly, and that class doesn't implement `Serializable`.

Comment: http://www.javatpoint.com/serialization-in-java

Comment: Posted the code sir. Please have a look to it @TilakMadichetti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The simplest solution is to find the class that throws the exception and make it implement the `Serializable` interface. However, this may not be feasible if the class that throws the exception belongs to a third-party library.
2. In case the class refers to non-serializable objects and these objects should not be serialized, then, you can declare these objects as `transient`. Once a field of a class is declared as `transient`, then, it is ignored by the serializable runtime.

Comment: yeah ohk.. i got that `transient` thing but the issue is i am not able to figure out which of the property of the `Purchase` class is not ready to be serialized.

Comment: @surajmalviya its talking about db connectivity but i cant see any code related to db connectivity

Comment: i have updated the code please go through it .. The thing is the core code of DB is working and even the same code for other case is working fine. I am not able to figure out the root cause satement in my code which is creating this mess.

Comment: @surajmalviya the issue is with either `updateBalance` or `makeTransaction`, please check the schema of table `stransaction` and `net_balance` for type mismatch

Comment: if i am commenting the last statement of `makePurchase` then everything is going fine. I have even verified the type mismatchings and column order integrities and also the `updateBalance` and evrything as i mentioned except of  `saveInvoice` is working fine. @piyush_jaiswal